# jmeter regular expression extract part of returned url

Tags: regex, url

I need to extract a part of returned url from a GET Request. As the following :

```
https://happy.new.year/idp/1Z8a8/resumeSAML20/idp/startSSO.ping
```

I need to extract this value: `1Z8a8` and I need to put it into a new POST request.

Which regular expression do I have to use in regular expression extractor configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
(.+?)\/
```

This will match the parts between slashes. The one you want is the fourth match.